# Beginner programming in c, cant find segmentation fault, as well as loop is not being properly executed

Tags: c

I have a two functions in my code, one that reads a file for data, and then that function(int readAPollutant) is called in another function(struct Location readData) which prompts the user for three data types(comes from three different files of each the same location). My first problem is that when the user is prompted for one of these files, and a file that does not exist is entered in, the code should ask for that same file again, but instead my code is simply printing the error, but not asking for that same file again, it moves to prompt the user for the next file. if a file with a location that is not the same as the previous is entered in, it should loop to ask for that same file again (this part of the code works). Also, once I get to asking for the last file, I get a segmentation error. I have no errors, just warnings of unused variables. The data from the file is also stored in a struct.

I am currently using do while loops in to make sure that the location is the same in readData, and I have the close file if the file does not exist in the readAPollutant function.(these are just three functions of my code).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

//#include "A3_functions.h"

#define MAX_LOCATIONS 10
#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 256
#define MAX_DATES 31
#define HOURS 24

#define O3_INDEX 0
#define NO2_INDEX 1
#define PM2_5_INDEX 2

typedef struct Location{
    char locationName[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
    char dates[MAX_DATES][MAX_STRING_SIZE];
    int numDays;

    float pollutantAverages[3][MAX_DATES];

    float standardAQHIs[MAX_DATES];
    float seasonalAQHIs[MAX_DATES];

} Location;

// TODO create (at least) 5 these functions:

float getAverage(float pollutants[24]) {
    float sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
        if (pollutants[i] >= 0 && pollutants[i] != 9999) {
            sum += pollutants[i];
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return sum / count;
}


int readAPollutantFile(char filename[], char location[], float pollutantAverages[], char dates[][MAX_STRING_SIZE]) {

    //char aLocation[MAX_STRING_SIZE];

    //opens the file
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: file %s does not exist\n", filename);
        return 0;
    }

    int charRead = 1;
    int numLines = 1;
    char line[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
    char date[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
    float pollutants[24];
    char storedStrings[MAX_STRING_SIZE][MAX_STRING_SIZE];
    char lineRead[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
    int numWords = 0;

    while (charRead != 0) {

        charRead = readLine(line, MAX_STRING_SIZE, fp);

        if (numLines == 4) {
                numWords = splitLineIntoStrings(line, storedStrings, ",");//reading location on the fourth line
                strcpy(location, storedStrings[0]);

                //remove everytging after the location name
                char* space = strchr(location, ' ');
                if (space != NULL) {
                *space = '\0';
                }
        }
        //skip to line 15 to start reading the data
        if ((numLines > 14) && (numLines < 46)) {

                //take each pollutant value and make it into a string, along with the date, station id, and type of pollutant
                numWords = splitLineIntoStrings(line, storedStrings, ",");
                for (int i=0; i<24;i++) {
                        pollutants[i] = atof(storedStrings[i+3]);
                }

                //call getAverage to calculate average
                float avg = getAverage(pollutants);
                pollutantAverages[numLines-15] = avg;

                //copy dates into dates array
                strcpy(dates[numLines-15], storedStrings[2]);

        }

        numLines++;

    }



    fclose(fp);
    return numLines - 15;
}

struct Location readData() {

        //declsre vars
        struct Location loc;
        float pollutantAverages[3][MAX_STRING_SIZE];
        char o3File[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
        char no2File[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
        char pm2_5File[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
        char location[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
        //char aLocation[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
        char dates[MAX_DATES][MAX_STRING_SIZE];


        //Read in data for O3 for a location
        printf("Please enter the filename for the O3 csv file\n");
        scanf("%s", o3File);



        //call readAPollutant to read o3 data
        int numLinesO3 = readAPollutantFile(o3File, location, pollutantAverages[0], dates);
        strcpy(loc.locationName, location);
        memcpy(loc.dates, dates, sizeof(dates));
        memcpy(&loc.pollutantAverages[0], &pollutantAverages[0], sizeof(pollutantAverages));

        //print statement
        printf("%f", pollutantAverages[0][0]);

     do {

        //Read in data for no2 for a location
        printf("Please enter the filename for the NO2 csv file for %s\n", loc.locationName);
        scanf("%s", no2File);

        //call readAPollutants to read no2 data and read the pollutant data from the file
        int numLinesNO2 = readAPollutantFile(no2File, location, pollutantAverages[1], dates);
        memcpy(loc.pollutantAverages[1], pollutantAverages[1], sizeof(pollutantAverages));

        //print statement
        printf("%f", pollutantAverages[0][1]);

    } while (strcmp(loc.locationName, location)!=0);

    do {
        //Read in data for no2 for a location
        printf("Please enter the filename for the PM2_5 csv file for %s\n", loc.locationName);
        scanf("%s", pm2_5File);


        // TODO same as for O3
        int numLinesPM2_5 = readAPollutantFile(pm2_5File, location, pollutantAverages[2], dates);
        memcpy(loc.pollutantAverages[2], pollutantAverages[2], sizeof(pollutantAverages));

        //print statement
        printf("%s%s", location, loc.locationName);

    } while (strcmp(loc.locationName, location)!=0);
        // TODO
        // now that we read in the data and have the pollutant averages
        // calculate stadanrd aqhi for each day
        // then check if month is cool or warm
        // and calculate seasonal


    return loc;




}
```

[Image of desired flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yclyz.png)

Comment: What debugger are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
memcpy(loc.pollutantAverages[2], pollutantAverages[2], sizeof(pollutantAverages));
```

is the size of the whole array, not one row.

```
float pollutantAverages[3][MAX_STRING_SIZE];
```

and so you have broken the array bounds of `loc.pollutantAverages[2]`. It should be

```
memcpy(loc.pollutantAverages[2], pollutantAverages[2], sizeof loc.pollutantAverages[2]);
```

These arrays are **not congruent** anyway: in the `struct` you have

```
float pollutantAverages[3][MAX_DATES];
```

but locally you have

```
float pollutantAverages[3][MAX_STRING_SIZE];
```

so it's unclear to me whether you should use the size of the source array, or of the destination array, or if that's a bug.

Comment: Similarly for the first two rows of the array.

Answer (score 1):

> My first problem is that when the user is prompted for one of these files, and a file that does not exist is entered in, the code should ask for that same file again, but instead my code is simply printing the error, but not asking for that same file again, it moves to prompt the user for the next file.

You should restructure:

1. Don't prompt for the filename in the *caller* of `readAPollutantFile` only to have the function reject it.
2. Move the `scanf` [and `fopen`] into a separate function (e.g. `open_file` below). That function should prompt for the filename, open it, and *loop* if it can't open the file.
3. Change the first argument of `readAPollutantFile` from `char filename[]` to `FILE *fp` and remove the `fopen` code.

---

Here's some sample code for what I mean:

```
FILE *
open_file(const char *type,const char *loc,char *filename)
{
    FILE *fp;

    while (1) {
        printf("Please enter the filename for the %s csv file",type);
        if (loc != NULL)
            printf(" for %s",loc);
        printf("\n");
        fflush(stdout);

        scanf("%s", filename);

        fp = fopen(filename,"r");
        if (fp != NULL)
            break;

        printf("Unable to open '%s' -- %s\n",filename,strerror(errno));
    }

    return fp;
}

#if 0
int
readAPollutantFile(char filename[], char location[], float pollutantAverages[],
    char dates[][MAX_STRING_SIZE])
#else
int
readAPollutantFile(FILE *fp, char location[], float pollutantAverages[],
    char dates[][MAX_STRING_SIZE])
#endif
{

    // char aLocation[MAX_STRING_SIZE];

    // opens the file
#if 0
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: file %s does not exist\n", filename);
        return 0;
    }
#endif

    // ELIDED: do calculations ...

    fclose(fp);

    return numLines - 15;
}

struct Location
readData()
{

    // declsre vars
    struct Location loc;
    float pollutantAverages[3][MAX_STRING_SIZE];
    char o3File[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
    char no2File[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
    char pm2_5File[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
    char location[MAX_STRING_SIZE];

    // char aLocation[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
    char dates[MAX_DATES][MAX_STRING_SIZE];

#if 1
    FILE *fp;
#endif

#if 0
    // Read in data for O3 for a location
    printf("Please enter the filename for the O3 csv file\n");
    scanf("%s", o3File, NULL);

    // call readAPollutant to read o3 data
    int numLinesO3 = readAPollutantFile(o3File, location, pollutantAverages[0],
        dates);
#else
    fp = open_file("O3",NULL,o3File);
    int numLinesO3 = readAPollutantFile(fp, location, pollutantAverages[0],
        dates);
#endif

    // ELIDE: stuff ...

    do {
#if 0
        // Read in data for no2 for a location
        printf("Please enter the filename for the NO2 csv file for %s\n",
            loc.locationName);
        scanf("%s", no2File);

        // call readAPollutants to read no2 data and read the pollutant data
        // from the file
        int numLinesNO2 = readAPollutantFile(no2File, location,
            pollutantAverages[1], dates);
#else
        fp = open_file("NO2",loc.locationName,no2File);

        int numLinesNO2 = readAPollutantFile(fp, location,
            pollutantAverages[1], dates);
#endif

        memcpy(loc.pollutantAverages[1], pollutantAverages[1],
            sizeof(pollutantAverages));

        // print statement
        printf("%f", pollutantAverages[0][1]);

    } while (strcmp(loc.locationName, location) != 0);

    // similar changes for other file opens ...

    return loc;
}
```

---

In the code above, I've used `cpp` conditionals to denote old vs. new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif
```

Note: this can be cleaned up by running the file through `unifdef -k`